# Is it better to use the State monad, or to pass state recursively?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm just learning Haskell, and trying to figure out the most idiomatic way to implement a line of sight algorithm.

The demo code I found uses the state monad, but it seem simpler to me (I'm just a beginner) to pass state recursively.  What am I missing here?  Are there performance problems?

Find code at: http://www.finalcog.com/bresenham-algorithm-idiomatic-haskell

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Well recursion can be slower and cause your stack to grow

Comment: @Tnay Recursion can also be faster and run in constant stack space.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the State monad and the ST ("State Thread", which your article uses) monad are not the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can become a bit verbose to pass state everywhere. Also, the state monad is well known by most haskell coders so they'll know what you're doing. If you hand-roll your own, outside a monad, it can be tricky to discern what your code does.

I find the state monad neat for encapsulating state changes, it's pretty obvious what part of your code is stateful (i.e. alters or depends on state) w.r.t. the rest of the pure stuff.

Comment: Learning how to use monads well is also important, so using them in a situation where you know how you would accomplish the same thing otherwise can be a good way to learn.

Answer (score 11):

For larger programs, it is better to hide the state passing plumbing in the monad. There is less risk of error then.

Answer (score 3):

An advantage of using a monad to pass on state rather than passing on state explicitly, is that there are many useful combinators defined for monads that you can use.